# How can I call cancel while copying file? (using copy file ex function with copy progress routine callback function)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'd created one cancel button to stop the file copy. What should I call in Copy Progress Routine in order to cancel the file copy.

```
DWORD CALLBACK CopyProgressRoutine(LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize, 
LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred, LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize, 
LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred, DWORD dwStreamNumber, DWORD 
dwCallbackReason, HANDLE hSourceFile, HANDLE hDestinationFile, LPVOID 
lpData)
{   
HWND hWndDlg = (HWND)lpData;
static HWND hwndIDC_PROGRESS1;
hwndIDC_PROGRESS1 = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS_DATA_OF_RETRIEVING);

DOUBLE Percentage = ((DOUBLE)TotalBytesTransferred.QuadPart / 
    (DOUBLE)TotalFileSize.QuadPart) * 100;

switch (dwCallbackReason)
{
    case CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED:
    break;

    case CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH:
    if (cancel_Copy_File!=false) // cancel_copy_file is still undefined
        {
            return PROGRESS_CANCEL;
        }
    break;
}
return PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. As I understand you changes cancel_Copy_File global variable in the button on clicked message handler. Probably the problem here is that all your activities run in the same thread. You should either run copy function in a new thread or use so-called "message pumping" concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You react only on `CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH` which in most cases you will get only once. `CopyFileEx` copies file in chunks and after each chunk calls callback with `reson == CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED`. In reality you don't need to differentiate between this cases and handle both with same code.

```
DWORD CALLBACK CopyProgressRoutine(LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize, 
    LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred, LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize, 
    LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred, DWORD dwStreamNumber, DWORD 
    dwCallbackReason, HANDLE hSourceFile, HANDLE hDestinationFile, LPVOID 
    lpData)
{   
    HWND hWndDlg = (HWND)lpData;
    static HWND hwndIDC_PROGRESS1;
    hwndIDC_PROGRESS1 = GetDlgItem(hWndDlg, IDC_PROGRESS_DATA_OF_RETRIEVING);

    DOUBLE Percentage = ((DOUBLE)TotalBytesTransferred.QuadPart / 
        (DOUBLE)TotalFileSize.QuadPart) * 100;

    /* If you copy on GUI thread, you need to pump messages with
       while ( PeekMessage( ... ) ) { ... }
    */

    return cancel_Copy_File ? PROGRESS_CANCEL : PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yoy need to return `PROGRESS_CANCEL` from `CopyProgressRoutine`, as described here:
LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE callback function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nc-winbase-lpprogress_routine

Return Value:

`PROGRESS_CANCEL` Cancel the copy operation and delete the destination file.

`PROGRESS_CONTINUE` Continue the copy operation.

See the full list in MSDN article.